# How to cast type-erased std::function?

Tags: c++

I need to implement observable object, that notifies observers when some value changes. 
Some observers don't need to know the value. Some observers are type-erased but have reflection metadata to interpret void* and read data. And some observers use type-safe interface.

To support all kinds of observers I store everything inside `std::function<void(void*)>`.
But this requires extra layer of indirection (extra `std::function`) to convert from type-erased to type safe interface:

```
template<typename T> 
struct observable {
      std::vector<std::function<void(void *)>> funcs;

      void add_observer(std::function<void(void *)> &&f) 
      { 
         funcs.emplace_back(f); 
      }

      void add_observer(std::function<void(T&)> &&f)
      {
        // extra layer of indirection
        add_observer([f](void * val)
        {
          f(*reinterpret_cast<T*>(val));
        });
      }

      void notify(T& new_val) 
      {
         for (const& f : funcs) { f(&new_val); }
      }
};
```

Is it possible to cast `function<void(void*)>` to `function<void(T&)>` to avoid this inefficiency?

Comment: Looks like reinterpret_cast function<void(void*)> to function<void(T*)> works. But not to function<void(T&)>

Comment: We need to know more about the problem you're trying to solve to offer a good solution. `reinterpret_cast`ing a `std::function` is all kinds of wrong. There might be a better solution if we had more context

Comment: Reinterpreting a function pointer is still UB but is more likely to work due to the simplicity of a function pointer.

Comment: The problem described in the question. I have observable<T> object that has two types of observers : type-safe and type erased. I'm searching for most efficient implementation.

Comment: @Kerndog73 No `std::function` or function pointer is `reinterpret_cast` in OPs code and `reinterpret_cast`ing a function pointer to another function pointer for storage is fine as long as you cast it back the original type before calling it.

Comment: No, I don't know the original type when I call. So it works with T* and void*. But as I understood it is still UB.

Comment: @random I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. Could you provide a more concrete example in the question?

Comment: @Kerndog73 I've modified code in question to be more precise about my current solution

Comment: You could use two separate vectors

Comment: I can use 2 separate vectors. However I wanted to move most of implementation to type-erased base class to reduce code bloat.

Comment: Why would you ever use the "type-erased function"? The sample code would be better if it only used `std::function<void(T&)>`.

Comment: @aschepler I have clients that don't know T (not written in C++), but have reflection metadata and use C-style void* interface.

Comment: Maybe this would make more sense if you show an example client using `void*`.

Comment: Boost [Signals2](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/signals2.html) can be used to implement observable objects, which notifies observers when some value changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the observer callable to be stored directly instead of as `std::function`. Then you can avoid the double-`std::function` indirection (assuming the caller isn't already providing a `std::function` as argument to `add_observer`):

```
template<typename F>
void add_observer(F &&f)
{
  funcs.emplace_back([f=std::forward<F>(f)](void * val) mutable
  {
    f(*static_cast<T*>(val));
  });
}
```

---

Note that forwarding the callable into the lambda may be more performant if the callable has large state and also note that `static_cast` is sufficient to cast `void*` to another object pointer type.

---

The concrete cast for `std::function` that you are asking for does not exist. It would require `std::function` to make assumptions about the intended semantics of `void*` -> `T&` that are not at all obvious.

Comment: don't quite understood `f=std::forward<F>(f)`. Won't it be move-constructed, if I just put `[f](..){...}` there?

Comment: @random No, `[f]` will always capture-by-copy. You need the generalized capture syntax and `f = f` is also not sufficient since `f` is an lvalue, so move constructors would not be considered if even if `f` has rvalue reference type from the universal reference.

Comment: also found that lambda should be declared as mutable. otherwise it won't support functors with non-const operator()

Comment: @random Yes that is true. My function also doesn't take into account `const T&` arguments, which would require `const_cast`'s and it also doesn't take care of an observer expecting a pointer directly. You will need to use SFINAE or `if constexpr` to select the correct behavior depending on the expected argument type of `F` and even then there is some ambiguity because `F` may have overloaded call operators.

Answer (score -2):

No.

There are solutions not involving std function, but they are insane.

Comment: Are you saying the other answer is insane?

Comment: @Kerndog73 It doesn't answer the problem as described; convering one type-erasure type to another without copying a std function.  Which can only be done by rolling your own type erasure.